# On enter how to stop adding new row in TMSFMXEdit?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle, tms

I'm using TMSFMX tools to develop mobile app where TMSFMXEdit tool is by default multi-line means on enter new row gets generated in it and I don't want to allow user to add new row on enter or on pest. I want to keep it single row only.  Can anybody help me how to do it?

Comment: TMSFMXEdit is single line! which version are you using?

Comment: TMS FMX UI Pack 3.7.3.0

Comment: so weird. i checked it in Delphi 10.3 with TMS FMX UI Pack 3.7.3.0 and the TMSFMXEdit Control is just single line.

Comment: Have you checked in mobile by making any normal app? if not then make simple app with only TMSFMXEdit then install in mobile and check it.